# PRTG - NetFlow v9 on Cisco ASA 5520 not working

Tags: cisco-asa, monitoring, netflow

We have a PRTG Probe `192.168.4.4` in our office's Domain Controller, and we are trying to configure NetFlow on our leased Cisco ASA 5520 ver 8.2(5)
We have done the following on the Cisco:

```
conf t
access-list netflow-traffic extended permit ip any any
class-map netflow traffic
 match acl netflow
flow-export destination inside 192.168.4.4 2056
policy-map global-policy
flow-export event-type all destination 192.168.4.4
```

Checking commands:

```
show flow-export counters  --> it shows few results
show logging flow-export
```

On the PRTG it is still showing not active; am I doing something wrong?

Comment: On which interfaces, in which direction are you applying NetFlow?

Comment: @Hadi QJ Please let me know if my answer below solve your problem.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether there are typos in your code lines above when you typed in or they are exactly what you have in your current configuration, but I noticed that:

- `class-map netflow traffic` seems not to be right.
- `match acl netflow` is wrong, it should be `match access-list
  netflow-traffic` as you named your ACL as `netflow-traffic`
- You may need to put netflow-related class-map under global policy-map
- You may need `delay flow-create` and/or `template timeout-rate`

I would propose the following lines (exclude `delay flow-create`, you can try if it still does not work):

```
!
access-list netflow-traffic extended permit ip any any
!
flow-export destination inside 192.168.4.4 2056
flow-export template timeout-rate 1
!
class-map netflow-traffic-class
 match access-list netflow-traffic
!
policy-map global_policy
 class netflow-traffic-class
  flow-export event-type all destination 192.168.4.4
```